# Network class doesn't send data to delegate Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am new to Objective-C, I am trying to make a class that will handle `URLSession` tasks for the app in order to download and play a song from `SoundCloud` and pass it to to the `SongPlayer` class using `Protocol and Delegate`.

My NetworkManager.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol NetworkDelegateProtocol<NSObject>
-(void) didReceiveData:(id) data;
@end

@interface NetworkManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<NetworkDelegateProtocol>delegate;
-(void) requestSong: (NSString *) songUrlStr;

@end
```

My NetworkManager.m file:

```
#import "NetworkManager.h"

@implementation NetworkManager
-(void)requestSong: (NSString *) songUrlStr {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:songUrlStr];
    [[NSURLSession.sharedSession dataTaskWithURL: url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"failed to download song %@", error);
            return;
        }

        [self.delegate didReceiveData:data];
    }] resume];
}
@end
```

My SongPlayer.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

#import "NetworkManager.h"

@interface SongPlayer : NSObject <NetworkDelegateProtocol ,AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property NetworkManager *networkManager;

@property (nonatomic, weak) AVAudioPlayer *songPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSData *songData;

@property BOOL didDownload;

@end
```

And finally my SongPlayer.m file:

```
#import "SongPlayer.h"

@implementation SongPlayer

NetworkManager *networkManager;
BOOL didDownload;

AVAudioPlayer *songPlayer;
NSData *songData;

-(void) didReceiveData: (NSData *) data {
    songData = data;
    didDownload = YES;
    [songPlayer play];
}
@end
```

I set the `SongPlayer` class as `Delegate` in the `SongPlayerViewController` class here:

```
@implementation SongPlayerViewController {

    SongPlayer *songPlayer;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

songPlayer = [[SongPlayer alloc]init];

    songPlayer.networkManager.delegate = songPlayer;
NSArray *songUrlArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: baseSongUrlStr, songId, endSongUrlStr, nil];
NSString *requestUrl = [songUrlArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NetworkManager *network = [[NetworkManager alloc] init];
[self setupSong];

[network requestSong:requestUrl];
```

}
    @end

When I try to `debug` it, the `dataTaskWithURL` is completed and the `NetworkManager` class receives the `data`, but it never sends it to the `Delegate`.

Thank you in advance.

P.S: In my `NetworkManager` class I have another `URLSession` task to get list of songs by name which works perfectly.

Comment: Where are you calling the requestSong?

Comment: My mistake, I am calling requestSong in viewDidLoad in SongPlayerViewController class, just edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: And where are you initializing the SongPlayer?

Comment: urgh, in the same place (viewDidLoad in SongPlayerViewController class)

Comment: Your method signature is wrong. -(void) didReceiveData:(id) data; should be id not NSData.

Comment: @SachinVas this is the method signature as I am using this protocol to receive song array in different view controller class -(void) didReceiveData:(NSMutableArray<Song *> *)data which works fine

Comment: @Sachin Vas is right. Then you should change the definition in your NetworkDelegateProtocol. It is defined as didReceiveData:(id). Not sure it matters in Objective-C though.

Comment: @TimTwoToes from what I know (id) means any data type, as long as I provide the data type when I use it. From what I understand I need to use (id) because one time the parameter I pass is NSMutableArray in on view controller and the other time I pass NSData as shown above in SongPlayer

Comment: You are using the local variable which is never being retained in the viewDidLoad of Controller. You need to use the SongPlayer NetworkManager.

Comment: Do you mean when I am setting the delegate or calling requestSong? or both perhaps

Comment: @SachinVas changed  songPlayer.networkManager.delegate = songPlayer; to network.delegate = songPlayer; in View Controller and it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Sachin Vas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6649262/sachin-vas) suggested in his comment, I had to change songPlayer.networkManager.delegate = songPlayer; to network.delegate = songPlayer; in View Controller and it works!
Thanks again [Sachin Vas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6649262/sachin-vas) .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `networkManager` property on your `SongPlayer` might be nil when you are setting the delegate, so ... in Objective-C nothing happens.

```
@implementation SongPlayerViewController {

    SongPlayer *songPlayer;

...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    songPlayer = [[SongPlayer alloc]init];
    NetworkManager *network = [[NetworkManager alloc] init];   // do this here
    songPlayer.networkManager = network;                       // set before use
    songPlayer.networkManager.delegate = songPlayer;

    NSArray *songUrlArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: baseSongUrlStr, songId, endSongUrlStr, nil];
    NSString *requestUrl = [songUrlArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    [self setupSong];

    [network requestSong:requestUrl];
} 
@end
```